# Azure VM running Windows Server not receiving license activation response

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, windows-server

I have a Azure VM running Windows Server. It is not receiving a license activation response. I have been using the following Microsoft public documentations as reference:

- [Troubleshoot Azure Windows virtual machine activation problems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-activation-problems)
- [Guidelines for troubleshooting the Key Management Service (KMS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/activation-troubleshoot-kms-general)

I have confirmed that the Azure VM can access the Azure KMS server endpoint **kms.core.windows.net** on port 1688 (verified through Telnet). So networking issues do not seem to be the problem.

I have also verified through the Event Logs that the VM is sending out several **activation requests** to the correct Azure KMS server endpoint (event ID 12288). However, that same VM is not receiving any activation responses (event ID 12289). Screenshot below:

[image: Event Log 12288]

What could be going on? This is a newly deployed Azure VM and its image is directly from the Azure marketplace. Is there maybe a ***time delay*** between a new Azure VM and the Azure KMS server actually responding to the activation request? And if so, how long is that delay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the screenshots below, the VM was stopped sometime after 2/17/2020 7:14 PM UTC. It was then restarted sometime shortly before 2/19/2020 2:06 PM UTC. Upon the VM being restarted, that VM's activation request was quickly paired with a successful activation response.

Detail of Activation Request (event ID 12288):
[image]

Detail of Activation Response (event ID 12289):
[image]

As long as Windows Server VMs do not delay in being activated being their 30-day grace period, a small delay in activation **is not a problem**.

For further Windows Server activation issues in Azure, the troubleshooting steps to be followed are documented here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/supportingwindows/troubleshooting-windows-activation-failures-on-azure-vms